# Matlab error Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent

Tags: matlab, concatenation

I have error when trying to create `classifier_pattern` as seen below.

```
classifier_pattern = [25,'no','fine','no';200,'no','hot','yes';100,'no','rainy','no';125,'yes','rainy','no';030,'yes','rainy','no';300,'yes','fine','yes';055,'yes','hot','no';140,'no','hot','no';020,'yes','fine','no';175,'yes','fine','yes';110,'no','hot','yes'];
```

> Matlab error Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

I'm not sure why this is happening. Later I try and also use `vertcat` with another similar matrix, which also fails.

Comment: good but it apear another error

Comment: Undefined operator '>=' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are trying to use character arrays (e.g. `'no'`) within a *matrix*. You should be using a cell array for mixed data types.

Look at a simple example

```
m = [1, 2, 'no'];
% >> m = '  no' because you have attempted character array concatenation, 
%               and the 1 and 2 are assumed to be ASCII whitespaces

m = [1, 2, 'no';
     3, 4, 'ya;]
% >> m = ['  no'; '  ya'] same story, now it's a 2*4 character array

m = [1, 2, 'no';
     3, 4, 'yes']
% ERROR: Dimensions not consistent
% This is because you're trying vertical concatenation of 4 and 5 element character arrays.
```

Fix this by using cell arrays:

```
m = {1, 2, 'no';
     3, 4, 'yes'};
% >> m = 2*3 cell, as expected.
```